# Espacios opcionales en expresión regular para validar campo

Tags: javascript, regex

Estaba haciendo una expresión regular para validar un campo de un formulario y me ha surgido una duda.

```
var expReg = /^([A-Z]|[a-z]){4}\s\d{6}\s\d/;
```

Esa es mi expresión regular. Coincide con un campo parecido a este:

> ABCD 123456 7

- Cuatro letras.
- Un espacio.
- Seis números.
- Un espacio.
- Un último número.

Dado que es un campo que seguramente se utilice mucho y con prisa, quiero testear que pueda no haber espacios. No suelo utilizar mucho expresiones regulares así que, lo que he hecho es crear una nueva sin espacios y testearlas ambas:

```
var expReg = /^([A-Z]|[a-z]){4}\d{6}\d/;
```

Sin embargo ahora tengo la duda de si sería posible hacer esto en una sola expresión, es decir, poder decirle que en un punto concreto pueda haber o no un espacio.

¿Existe una forma de hacerlo o es obligado crear y comprobar ambas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta agregandole la condicional `?` en las expresiones `\s` :

```
/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){4}\s?\d{6}\s?\d$/
```

Esto lo que hace es que los espacios sea opcionales. Tambien deberias de agregarle la expresion `$` al final de la expresión que en conjunto con `^` indica que lea todo el string:

```js
function validar()
{
  var entrada = document.getElementById("entrada");
  
  if(/^[A-Za-z]{4}\s?\d{6}\s?\d$/.test(entrada.value))
  {
    console.log("valor valido");
  }
  else{
    console.log("valor invalido");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada" />
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Tanto **ABCD 123456 7** como **ABCD1234567** son correctos, sin embargo **ABCD 1234567** y **ABCD123456 7** también son validos debido a la condicional de los espacios. Si quieres evitar esto entonces utiliza expresiones de grupo de captura donde solo es valido si se cumplen una de las dos reglas que deseas:

```js
function validar()
{
  var entrada = document.getElementById("entrada");
  
  if(/^([A-Za-z]{4}\s\d{6}\s\d|[A-Za-z]{4}\d{6}\d)$/.test(entrada.value))
  {
    console.log("valor valido");
  }
  else{
    console.log("valor invalido");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="entrada" />
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Esto significa que si no se cumple a expresion donde acepta los espacios:

```
[A-Za-z]{4}\s\d{6}\s\d
```

Entonces se procedera a validar la siguiente expresion donde no se acepta los espacios

```
|[A-Za-z]{4}\d{6}\d
```

De lo contrario sera invalido.

---

No se si habras notado que le hice algunos cambios a tu expresión. La expresión `([A-Z]|[a-z]){6}` se puede reducir a `[A-Za-z]{6}` y así evitar que la expresion de match con otro string y sea arojado en el resultado. Tambien evita que se hagan 2 búsquedas tanto para mayúscula como para minúsculas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Es una respuesta super completa que me ayuda muchísimo. Es indiferente si ponen espacios o no o dónde los pongan (siempre que sea dónde estaban determinados) así que me quedo con la primera opción. Gracias :)

Comment: Unos detalles: `\s` no son espacios sino mucho más que eso. Para que sean espacios, simplemente se usan... espacios. `\d{6}\d` es lo mismo que `\d{7}`... Y realmente no conviene jamás usar un grupo con captura. Si sólo se quiere agrupar, conviene `(?:`...`)`